# WPF: Similar xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

So i have some similar windows and their xamls are the same. Obviously duplicated code is not good. And i would like my windows shared xaml from only file. I created DataTepmlate containing common xaml and placed it into ResourceDictionary. But i don't know how to place DataTemplate from resource dictionary into xaml file.

my datatemplate:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PeriodicTable.View.CollectionViews.CollectionTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox  Name="Lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Entity}"  
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" >

              <!-- lots and lots of code -->

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

my Resources.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:collectionViews="clr-namespace:PeriodicTable.View.CollectionViews"
                    xmlns:collectionViewModels="clr-namespace:PeriodicTable.ViewModel.ViewModel.CollectionViewModels">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComonCollectionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type collectionViewModels:PeriodsCollectionViewModel}" >
        <collectionViews:CollectionTemplate />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

File where i would like to put my datatemplate:

```
<Window x:Class="PeriodicTable.View.CollectionViews.PeriodCollectionWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="PeriodWindow" Height="350" Width="750" >

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>        
    </ResourceDictionary>

     what i should write here to place my DataTemplate from Resources.xaml?
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`ContentControl`** and set its **`ContentTemplate`** to the resource declared in resource file.

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ComonCollectionTemplate}"/>
```